# problem with $match and request.params.id in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I'm trying to get a department by it's `_id` from collection in Mongodb using `$lookup` and `$match` with the `_id` by receiving the `_id` from the request parameters.

However I get an empty array as my result, and when I change the `request.params.id` with static value like 2 or 1 it returns the data with no problem .. any solution ?

```
    DepartmentRouter.get("/departments/:id", (request, response) => {
    departmentSchema.aggregate([
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "students",
                localField: "_id",
                foreignField: "Department",
                as: "studentsObject"
            }
        },
        {
            $match: {
                _id: request.params.id
            }
        }
    ]).then(data => {
        response.send(data);
    }).catch(error => {
        response.send(error);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`request.params.id` comes as string (assuming you don't use any specific middleware to re-cast it).

All you have to do is [cast](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html) is to an `ObjectId` type. like so:

```
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID

{
     $match: {
         _id: new ObjectId(request.params.id)
     }
}
```

- Also a performance tip, Move the `$match` stage to be before the `$lookup` stage so you don't perform a lookup (which is expensive) to all the redundant documents.

Answer (score 0):

guys i found the solution , i had to make a new number object using Number

```
               $match: {
                   _id: Number(request.params.id)
               }
```